# Java JSON parsing

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea

I ran into trouble when I worked with a project, then switched to another one and after some time returned to the first project.

The weird thing here is that after returning to the old project somewhy the JSON parsing doesn't work anymore the way it used to.

It is a maven project and all the dependencies are the same as before.

So, what happens is that for example my IntelliJ doesn't recognize URL-s any more, an image from the console before:

[image: tere]

and now:

[image: tere]

As you can see the URL-s were blue and clickable, now as plain text.

Also, when parsing the JSON array, I was earlier able to do something like that:

```
number = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("version");
```

And it would have returned a string, but what happens now is that I get an error:

```
INFO: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["version"] not a string.
```

I'm using these imports:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

I know that it may seem quite vague now, but feel free to ask additional questions.

Edit: The line in the JSON:

```
version: 36928,
```

Comment: Sounds like the JSON structure has changed, if you post an example of the processed JSON it will be easier to help.

Comment: The thing is that another developer is still working on the same project and in his computer - everything works. The line that gives the error in JSON is as follows:

version: 36928,

Comment: `"36928"` is a String, `36928` is a number. Try with getInt("version") to get the number value

Comment: @AxelH Thanks, we already tried that and it works, but it means we would need to refactor a lot of our code. We're currently trying to find out what is different in the setup's or what's cousing it because the same code works on another PC.

Comment: Same code, same library version, same JSON? Well I can assure you that one of those are different. You can run a diff on both project to compare them. But the IDE is not responsible of the runtime. This is different for the URL.

Comment: The JSON should look like `"version": 36928,` right?

Comment: Is JSONObject from javax.json? 
If yes, maby the java was updated and the behaivior was changed?

Comment: I already answered the question, please check the answer, thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was different, was the JDK version and bit mode. I had a bit newer JDK installed and 64-bit, the other PC had older JDK and 32-bit. I am not entirely sure, what in those is different and caused the problem, but it is now working again.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Jackson ArrayNode and ObjectNode instead of JSONArray and JSONObject.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
Object obj = new Object();
arrayNode.add(mapper.createObjectNode().put("version", "Hello Stack!"));
arrayNode.addPOJO(obj);
arrayNode.get(0).get("version");
```

And also it's better to use this Maven dependency for including jackson:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The doc is here: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html

Comment: Why to change library when the first one works fine ? The problem was about a change in behavior in a working code. This is a lot of update to do...